# Centralizing management of chrome packaged apps in private network

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

- Is it possible to declarative install, uninstall, update [chrome
  packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) on client machines from server (or make all this
  operations with system scripts)?
- Is it possible to make local shell
  aplication to navigate between chrome packaged apps?

Use case: educational private network (schoolclassroom) based on chrome apps. After loading device, user see custom shell. User can navigate between chrome applications, using shell. User do not touch system, or chrome at all.
Also, aministrator could add application on every client system, using some scripted software management system...

Comment: http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/admin/

Comment: If your question is about how to build such a system, it is too broad: your question should be narrowly focused on a particular problem. If your question is about where to find such a system, it is off-topic, because resource requests (for books, software, etc.) are off-topic. You might better luck on the Chromium Apps Google Group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps

Comment: Question is about interacting with chrome packaged apps from scripts, to build such system. From docs I found only manual way to install applications on client system from chrome web store.